# How to limit SQL query to a number in a row (id-column)?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

How do I limit SQL data output to the "id" number? I want to fetch the up to the id of number 10 which is 14 rows. How would I do that? I tried with a sub query but I read that sub-queries are not supported after the LIMIT keyword.

The picture shows what should be outputted in the SQL query.

[image]

Comment: post the query you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID < 11`

Unless I'm not understanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count` to get the number of rows before that id, and add one to it, e.g.:

```
SELECT count(*)+1 AS index 
FROM test
WHERE id < 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
    FROM Table
    WHERE ID BETWEEN value1 AND value2
```